# Polar Curve ArcLength Exact

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework

Find the exact length of the polar curve

```
r-2cosθ (θ,0,π)
```

I tried regular `ArcLength` and it didn't work.

Comment: Could it be you made a mistake in writing the equation?  This is a polar curve then might be you are plotting r vs. Theta in polar coordinates?

Comment: Since this is homework, I'm guessing you're supposed to use whatever method you're learning in your calculus class to solve this and not built-in MMA functions. If you're interested in how to go about this in MMA, I would suggest you show that you have an answer worked out by other means and ask how to verify that in MMA.

Answer (score 2):

If the interpretation is $r=2\cos(t)$, i.e. a circle:

```
r[t_] := {2 Cos[t] Cos[t], 2 Cos[t] Sin[t]}
tr = TrigReduce[r[t]]
ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
Integrate[Sqrt[FullSimplify[D[tr, t].D[tr, t]]], {t, 0, Pi}]
ArcLength[r[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative interpretation would be the following curve:

```
Manipulate[
 PolarPlot[r - 2 Cos[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}],
 {{r, 1}, 0, 10}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In that case:

```
Simplify[
 ArcLength[{r, r - 2 Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, "Polar"],
 r >= 0
]

(* Out: 4 r *)
```